# Solid color based on 'Zone'

Tags: r, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

There are 5 main Division (North, South, East, West & Central) and within these divisions, there are zones.

I would like to color the zone based on division, Not sure where the code went wrong?

Thank you!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPmUK.png)

Comment: Hi there. You are more likely to get a good answer, if you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a small example of your data used and your expected output. Posting data and/or code as images is not a top 10 method for sharing information on SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.